# Dynamic table output - each field appears twice before moving on

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone tell me why this is producing each of the field values twice before moving on to the next value?

```
$titles = array('invlineid','invoiceid','quantity','unitprice','itemdesc');
$headers = array('invlineid','invoiceid','quantity','unitprice','itemdesc');

$sql = "SELECT ";

foreach(array_combine($headers, $titles) as $header => $title)
{
    $sql .= "$header as $title,";
}

$sql .= "linetotal as linetotal";
$sql .= " FROM invoicelineitem";
$sql .= " WHERE invoiceid = 1096";

try
{
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error getting invoice line items.---' . $e . '----' . $sql;
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mincludes/error.html.php';
    exit();
}

if ($result !== false)
{
    $html_table = '<table>';
    $html_table .= '<thead><tr>';

    foreach($titles as $title)
    {
        $html_table .= "<th> $title </th>";
    }

    $html_table .= '</tr> </thead>';
    $html_table .= '<tbody id="dataTable">';

    foreach($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
    {
        $html_table .= '<tr>' . "\n";

        foreach($row as $col)
        {
            $html_table .= '<td>';
            $html_table .= '<input type=text name=' . $title;
            $html_table .= ' value=' . $col . '>';
            $html_table .= '</td>' . "\n";
        }

        $html_table .= '</tr>' . "\n";
    }
}

$html_table .= '</tbody> <tr> </table>';
```

When it hit the end of the individual record, it start a new line in the table, but again, produces each value twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your fetchAll() method

look here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

**PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set.**

you could do this to return an array with integer indexed column numbers

```
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)
```

Comment: Thank you I think what I am looking for is PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: Would using fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM) make it easier to dynamically add rows with JavaScript after the data is loaded?  Is this also a better approach for when I need to save any changes to the data?

Comment: Okay, so with the code above, can anyone tell me how I save changes to the data back to the database? I know I need to loop through the rows, but what I can't figure out is what my $_POST looks like to grab the values.

Comment: 1st question: I think it depends on the usecase. Normaly I prefer associative indexes, because it is easier to address a value, like $row['firstname'] makes it clear what kind of data is expected. 2nd question: When I understand you correct. You output your data, but now you want to be able to change them and insert back to the DB? I would make a html form around the table, set it to POST. While testing, you could print_r($_POST) to see what you get. Then trigger an INSERT to the database with the new data.